# Using bokeh and hover tool in python

Tags: python, pandas, hover, bokeh

I need to make an interactive dot plot in bokeh using Python. Basically, I need to make a map using the latitudes and longitudes to show people that own these different pets.

The type variable has either dog, cat, bird, lizard, or other. Dots that are blue must show dog owners, red dots show cat owners, green show lizard owners, and pink show bird owners. I need to delete the 'other' values from the type variable because I don't want that on the map.

I also need help with the hover tool because when I scroll over the dots, I want to see the type of pet and latitude/longitude of that dot.

I am a beginner, so I have only figured out how to import the excel file to python.

Thanks!

The data looks like this:

```
Type Latitude Longitude 

Dog 41.9595 82.494997

Cat 41.4388 82.493585
```

And etc......

I wish I could attach the data set, but I can't seem to here. However, I don't need the exact results. Just an idea of the code to use to do this.

So far, this is what I have

```
import pandas as pd
Pet_Data = pd.read_csv('PetMap.csv',sep=',')
Pet_Data.head()
```

Comment: frankly, so far you have nothing. Maybe first you should check if bokeh can [display maps](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/geo.html) and test it. Or you will need to use Google Map API, or OpenStreet Map API or JavaScript library [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the community! Since you are fairly new it is a good idea to go through some tutorials. I myself have recently learned Bokeh for some really cool interactive charts.

I can show you a few tutorial links that helped me understand how to use Bokeh. I'll assume you're a complete beginner to the Python universe.

1. I would go through this [quickstart tutorial](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.10.0/docs/quickstart.html) to get a feel for how Bokeh works and getting comfortable navigating the docs

[HoveringTooltips](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html?highlight=tooltips#bokeh.models.tools.HoverTool.tooltips) is fairly simple to grasp once you understand what it needs.
That being said, I'll leave snippets of code for what would go into the tooltip argument within a Bokeh [figure](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html?highlight=figure#bokeh.plotting.figure.figure).

---

**Import necessities and print `Pet_data`**

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

# make sure we know what our table looks like
print(Pet_data)

    Type    Latitude    Longitude
0   Dog     41.9595     82.494997
1   Cat     41.4388     82.493585
```

**tooltip works something like this:**

1. Build a list of tuples(`TOOLTIP`) so hover tooltip will know what to
   access in your `Pet_data`
2. Initiate `figure` with `TOOLTIP` as argument, and store as variable `p`
3. Add `circle`s to `p` according to `Latitude`, `Longitude`
4. `show()` to print the chart

```
# 1
TOOLTIPS = [("type", "@Type"),       # this accesses 'Type' column
            ("lat", "@Latitude"),    # this accesses 'Latitude' column
            ("lat", "@Longitude")]   # this accesses 'Longitude' column

# 2
p = figure(tooltips=TOOLTIPS)        # initiate your figure and add TOOLTIP

# 3
p.circle(x='Latitude',               # circles on x
         y='Longitude',                and on y
         source=Pet_Data             # points to Pet_data df
         size=40)                    # simple circle size argument

# 4
show(p)                              # prints your figure
```

**Here is a print-screen with how the hover would look like:**
[image: Sample od Pet_data hover tooltip]

---

Now, granted this isn't a map like you would probably want since you have latitude and longitude values, but I just wanted to give you a simple example of how the hover tooltip works.

Hope it was helpful and good luck on your programming journey!